# If JavaScript Object Properties Are Empty Strings

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a form in Angular JS and want the submit button to be disabled (`ng-disabled`) until the models associated with the form are all populated, meaning that the strings are no longer empty and the integers are no longer zero.

Dealing with the numbers is easy enough, but the other models that aren't prices are all stored in one object, and are all empty strings. I was hoping there was an easy one line solution I could use in an `ng-disabled` to test if this object no longer contained empty strings for any of its properties.

Anyway, here is some code to make it clear:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="pickupDate" style="margin-top: 10px;">Pickup Date</label>
    <select name="pickupDate" ng-model="Oproperties.pickupDate">
        <option value="Tuesday">Tuesday - November 22nd</option>
        <option value="Wednesday">Wednesday - November 23rd</option>
        <option value="Thursday">Thursday - November 24th</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div class="form-group clear-fix">
    <div class="form-group" style="width:45%;float:left;">
        <label for="firstName">First Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Oproperties.firstName" placeholder="Jill">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group" style="width:45%;float:right;">
        <label for="lastName">Last Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Oproperties.lastName" placeholder="Smith">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="phone">Phone</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Oproperties.phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" ng-model="Oproperties.email" placeholder="yourname@email.com">
</div>
<div class="form-group" ng-repeat="(key, value) in breads | groupBy: 'Type'">
    <label class="itemTitle">@{{key}}</label>
    <div ng-repeat="bread in value">
        <label for="@{{bread.Name}}">@{{bread.Name}}</label>
        <select name="@{{bread.Name}} quantity" ng-options="quantityOption as quantityOption.value for quantityOption in quantityOptions track by quantityOption.value" ng-model="bread.quantity" ng-change="calculate()"></select>
        </select>
        <p class="price">@{{bread.Price|currency}} @{{bread.details}}</p>
    </div>
</div>
<button ng-disabled="Oproperties.containsEmptyString()&&totalPrice===0" ng-click="submitOrder()" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
```

The object looks like:

```
 $scope.Oproperties=
    {
    pickupDate:"",
    firstName:"",
    lastName:"",
    phone:"",
    email:""
    }
```

So basically, what would I do instead of `Oproperties.containsEmptyString()` which is currently just conceptual filler?

Comment: You should remove the inline styles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can wrap all your inputs inside a `form` element named `myForm`, then add the `required` attribute to your inputs and then set

`ng-disabled="myForm.$invalid"`

to your submit button.

Comment: Disabling a button does not stop the click handler running on it.

Answer (score 0):

You want to wrap your elements in a form and move the ng-click="submitOrder()" to the form at ng-submit="yourFormName.$valid && submitOrder()".

This will mean that the form only gets submitted if all the field are validated properly.